# Ensemble average of the interaction energy in second quantization

Tags: homework-and-exercises, second-quantization, matrix-elements

I have a problem with the calculation of the ensemble average for the second quantization interaction energy. It is definded as:
$$E_{int} = \left < \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j,k,l}w_{i,j,k,l} \hat{c}_{i}^{\dagger} \hat{c}_{j}^{\dagger} \hat{c}_{l} \hat{c}_{k} \right >$$

Obviously this should be:

$$E_{int} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{ijkl}w_{i,j,k,l} n_{k,l,i,j} $$

Where $n_{k,l,i,j}$ is the two-particle density matrix. In general the ensemble average for a two-particle operator is:
$$\left < \hat{A} \right > = \sum_{ijkl}A_{ijkl} n_{klij}$$
so for the matrix elements of the interaction energy:
$$ \left< s,p \right| \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j,k,l}w_{i,j,k,l} \hat{c}_{i}^{\dagger} \hat{c}_{j}^{\dagger} \hat{c}_{l} \hat{c}_{k} \left| t, v \right> $$
With $\left< s,p \right| = \left< s \right|\left< p \right|$ and $\left| t, v \right> = \left| t\right>\left| v\right>$.
Now i am a bit confused, i thought that $\hat{c}_{i}^{\dagger}$ would act on $\left< p \right|$ and $\hat{c}_{k}$ on $\left| t\right>$, so that the matrix-elements should look like that:
$$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j,k,l}w_{i,j,k,l}\delta_{i,p}\delta_{s,j}\delta_{t,k}\delta_{l,v} = \frac{1}{2}\omega_{p,s,t,v}$$
But when i put this into the ensemble average:
$$E_{int} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{s,p,t,v} \omega_{p,s,t,v} n_{t,v,s,p} \neq \frac{1}{2} \sum_{s,p,t,v}w_{s,p,t,v} n_{t,v,s,p}$$
It's not the same equation from above. Maybe i made a mistake with the matrix-elements?

Answer (score 0):

Since particles are indistinguishable,
$$
c_lc_k|t,v\rangle = \delta_{l,k}\delta{k,v}|0\rangle \pm \delta_{l,v}\delta{k,t}|0\rangle,
$$
where the sign depends on whether we deal with bosons or fermions. This is how the particle statistics is nicely incorporated into the second quantization formalism.

For detailed calculations of such terms one could look into Fetter & Walecka's book.